# Create File Stream Enabled Database in Network File (NAS Server)

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I want to create a filestream enabled SqlServer database using NAS server as the storage. I already passed the creation of DB step. Look at my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516515/creating-sql-server-database-with-data-and-log-file-on-synology-nas-server. I can create an ordinary db but couldn't managed to create filestream enabled DB. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is there anybody who knows if installing filestream enabled database SQLServer database by putting data files on NAS server is possible or not ?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't used Filestream enabled database before. Recently I had to install one for a document tracking and archiving software. I wanted to put the db on nas server because I don't have too much space on server harddisk. After some research I found out even I can put data and log files on nas I can not create filestream enabled database using nas so I installed totally on server instead. 
"Thank You" for Whom Who Viewed my question.

Ferda

Comment: Hi,I accepted thank you for your reminding ...